What consonants are silent in 'Ils sont impatients'?
My French course in Busuu teaches that the 's' at the end of 'impatients' is silent.
But I think the 't' (the second from the last) is also silent. I never heard the n sound pronounced in the recording.
What am I mistaken?

@XouDo On efface tout ce thread en commençant par mon commentaire?

@XouDo J'ai enlevé mon commentaire.

Yes, both the last T and the final S in impatients are silent.
You don't hear any N or M because neither of these consonants are pronounced as such here. They are only used to signal the nasal sounds in and an.
Note also that the letter T is pronounced like an S in that word.
